# Is it possible to make a call from iphone simulator and put some listeners to it?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios-simulator

I am new to iphone development.
I just want to know that is it possible to make a call from iphone simulator and then register some listeners to monitor this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No it's not possible.**Phone call,sms,Camera option,GPS,push notifications** etc.. we are not able to test it on simulator

Comment: Not sure about GPS, though. I believe you can enable location services and use CLLocationManager. Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: You can fake GPS location in the 'debug area' which is the 8th button from the left (arrow icon).

Comment: GPS works in simulator with test location, although the permissions will sometimes mess up at which point you must "Erase all content and settings". @AzaFromKaza

Answer (score 4):

You cant make calls from simulator. Though there is an option Hardware->Toggle in-call status bar, which changes the status bar.

Comment: how can we use it like realtime **Toggle in-call status bar**